# background div should have the same width and height only of the input text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to have the same size of width and height for my `.specialDiv` only of the input text field (no spans).
Now it looks like:

[image]

But I want to have like this:

[image]

Actual reason why I want this div is to use it like a background progress bar...
How can I fix this ?

http://jsfiddle.net/Yzxy3/345/

Comment: can u share jsfiddle link?

Comment: @MuhammetCanTONBUL http://jsfiddle.net/Yzxy3/345/

Comment: If you want to change the width of the input, you need to specify a width for the input-group div. `<div class="input-group" style="width:200px;">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you wont to like this:

```css
.input-group {
  position: relative;
}
.specialDiv {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100% - 78px);
}
.input-group .form-control {
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-md-12 column">
            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="/product/create" method="POST">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="product_price" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Price</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                            <div class="specialDiv"></div>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control bfh-number" id="product_price" placeholder="Price" data-min="0" data-max="9999999">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">.00</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, I want my special div to has the size only of the input text, not spans.

Comment: Thank you on that, that works, but why did u remove width ? For example I want to set 10% 50% or 100% width of the input width size. Is it possible to do ?

Comment: If you added 100% width it was goes outside of your input group so you need to calculate width for that.. i will added width in updated answer in `calc()` function